# How to change the keyboard layout system-wide ? (Affects Console and LightDM)

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to change the keyboard layout not in the Desktop but in the Console and and at the login screen. That is the default keyboard layout system-wide.

I am running Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20) but I would like this thread
to gather answers for most distributions.

My keyboard layout is `azerty` but I want to switch to `qwerty`.

Comment: I decided to create a new question because when I searched for "change keyboard layout system-wide", finding the answer was not straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Ubuntu** based distributions such as Linux Mint, you have to edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` (it's read-only so use your terminal editor with `sudo`)

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="qwerty"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

If you don't know what to write in the file, set the desired keymap in your desktop preferences and run `localectl`. it will give you the layout and variant names you need for XKBLAYOUT and XKBVARIANT.

In order for the change to take effect, reboot your computer.

Comment: You could at least specify your distro and its version for this question and answer to have any relevancy and value. Also, it would be nice to see the exact contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Do you think this solution is distro-specific ? I assumed most Linux distributions had a `/etc/default/keyboard` file

Comment: There's no such file in RHEL/Fedora - which are major Linux distros. Fedora has `/etc/locale.conf`: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/

Comment: Please replace your image with text.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the question and the answer.

Comment: Thank you for watching on our souls

Answer (score 1):

On **Fedora** and related systems, here is what the [docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/#s1-Changing_the_Keyboard_Layout) says :

### ***Changing the Keyboard Layout***

The keyboard layout settings enable the user to control the layout used on the text console and graphical user interfaces.

**Displaying the Current Settings**

As mentioned before, you can check your current keyboard layout configuration with the following command:

`localectl status`

*Example 4. Displaying the Keyboard Settings*

In the following output, you can see the keyboard layout configured for the virtual console and for the X11 window system.

```
~]$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

**Listing Available Keymaps**

To list all available keyboard layouts that can be configured on your system, type:

```
localectl list-keymaps
```

*Example 5. Searching for a Particular Keymap*

You can use grep to search the output of the previous command for a specific keymap name. There are often multiple keymaps compatible with your currently set locale. For example, to find available Czech keyboard layouts, type:

```
~]$ localectl list-keymaps | grep cz
cz
cz-cp1250
cz-lat2
cz-lat2-prog
cz-qwerty
cz-us-qwertz
sunt5-cz-us
sunt5-us-cz
```

**Setting the Keymap**

To set the default keyboard layout for your system, use the following command as root:

```
localectl set-keymap map
```

Replace map with the name of the keymap taken from the output of the `localectl list-keymaps` command. Unless the `--no-convert` option is passed, the selected setting is also applied to the default keyboard mapping of the X11 window system, after converting it to the closest matching X11 keyboard mapping. This also applies in reverse, you can specify both keymaps with the following command as root:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap map
```

If you want your X11 layout to differ from the console layout, use the `--no-convert` option.

```
localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap map
```

With this option, the X11 keymap is specified without changing the previous console layout setting.

*Example 6. Setting the X11 Keymap Separately*

Imagine you want to use German keyboard layout in the graphical interface, but for console operations you want to retain the US keymap. To do so, type as root:

```
~]# localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap de
```

Then you can verify if your setting was successful by checking the current status:

```
~]$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: de
```

Apart from keyboard layout (map), three other options can be specified:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap map model variant options
```

Replace model with the keyboard model name, variant and options with keyboard variant and option components, which can be used to enhance the keyboard behavior. These options are not set by default. For more information on X11 Model, X11 Variant, and X11 Options see the kbd(4) man page.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. Unfortunately it doesn't state how to set multiple layouts with variants. I'd like us-intl and de-neo, but `localectl set-x11-keymap de-neo,us-intl` doesn't work, neither does `de "" neo, us "" intl` as seen elsewhere. Any idea?

Comment: @Andy I am not sure about how can `localectl`  set two layouts at the same time for your keyboard... I guess what you want is a way to easily switch from one layout to another. I doubt  `localectl` can handle that (I may be wrong) but you can probably set this up through the graphical user interface as shown there : https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, localectl does allow to set a second "toggle keymap", but the login screen seems to ignore it. Thanks for the link, but it's quite outdated (Gnome 2) and does not describe how to influence the login screen. Currently the official docs describe how to set layout for login here, but only for one keymap: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/#s1-Changing_the_Keyboard_Layout